# iOS Touch Injection ala KIF doesn't work in some cases

Tags: ios, ios6, iphone-privateapi, kif-framework

I am developing an enterprise App that injects touches. The method I use is the same with the one seen in the KIF framework (see https://github.com/square/KIF/tree/master/Additions).

There is at least one case, where this method doesn't work:

**When the user taps on the device, the injection doesn't work anymore for scrollviews**. They don't scroll anymore, when I inject moving touch events. When the user himself scrolls at the device, the injection does work again. It seems like a state is not set with KIFs method, but it is set by iOS when a real touch occurs.

Does anyone know more about it ? Maybe has an idea wich state it could be ? I tried already several private API calls that sounded right, but none worked.

Here is some code, describing the method I used:

Touch down:

```
UITouch *touch = [[[UITouch alloc] initAtLocation:point inWindow:hitView.window] autorelease];
[touch setPhase:UITouchPhaseBegan];

UIEvent *newEvent = [hitView _eventWithTouch:touch];
[_activeTouchEvents addObject:touch];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendEvent:newEvent];
```

Touch move
    UITouch* touch = _activeTouchEvent;

```
[touch setPhase:UITouchPhaseMoved];
[touch setLocationInWindow:point];

UIEvent *newEvent = [hitView _eventWithTouch:touch];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendEvent:newEvent];
```

Touch up

```
UITouch* touch = _activeTouchEvent;
[touch setPhase:UITouchPhaseEnded];
[touch setLocationInWindow:point];

UIEvent *newEvent = [hitView _eventWithTouch:touch];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendEvent:newEvent];
[_activeTouchEvent release];
_activeTouchEvent = nil;
```

UIView (extension)

```
- (UIEvent *)_eventWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch;
{
    UIEvent *event = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] performSelector:@selector(_touchesEvent)];

    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.window];
    KIFEventProxy *eventProxy = [[KIFEventProxy alloc] init];
    eventProxy->x1 = location.x;
    eventProxy->y1 = location.y;
    eventProxy->x2 = location.x;
    eventProxy->y2 = location.y;
    eventProxy->x3 = location.x;
    eventProxy->y3 = location.y;
    eventProxy->sizeX = 1.0;
    eventProxy->sizeY = 1.0;
    eventProxy->flags = ([touch phase] == UITouchPhaseEnded) ? 0x1010180 : 0x3010180;
    eventProxy->type = 3001;

    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
    [event _clearTouches];
    [allTouches makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(autorelease)];
    [event _setGSEvent:(struct __GSEvent *)eventProxy];
    [event _addTouch:touch forDelayedDelivery:NO];

    [eventProxy release];
    return event;
}
```

UITouch (extension)

```
- (id)initAtLocation:(CGPoint)point inWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self == nil) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Create a fake tap touch
    _tapCount = 1;
    _locationInWindow = point;
    _previousLocationInWindow = _locationInWindow;

    UIView *hitTestView = [window hitTest:_locationInWindow withEvent:nil];

    _window = [window retain];
    _view = [hitTestView retain];
    _gestureView = [hitTestView retain];
    _gestureRecognizers = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[hitTestView gestureRecognizers]] retain];
    _phase = UITouchPhaseBegan;
    _touchFlags._firstTouchForView = 1;
    _touchFlags._isTap = 1;
    _timestamp = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] systemUptime];

    return self;
}

- (void)setPhase:(UITouchPhase)phase;
{
    _phase = phase;
    _timestamp = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] systemUptime];
}
```

Edit 1: Codeblock of "Touch down" was not right

Comment: Can you provide more context about when the injection starts and stops working and what you're using the injection for?  When scrolling occurs, the app switches run loop modes which can impact the behavior.